# Can you "sound up a room" the same way you can light it up?

Tags: verbs, word-usage, phrasal-verbs, analogy

I'm trying to say that a certain individual adds noise to any place he goes.

When someone, figuratively, enhances the mood of a room he enters we say "he lights up the room".

Is there any way to use *sound* as a verb to get the same idea across but with sound?

Comment: He brings *cacophony* wherever he goes! (Yes, I know it's not a verb; that's why it's not an answer.)

Comment: Does everyone in the room stop to pay attention to him or is he just a noisy new element to the room?

Comment: I don't understand how one could 'get the same idea across but with sound'. As you say, 'lights up' is used figuratively here. 'Sound up' isn't an idiom.

Comment: liven up a room.

Comment: You _can_ use "sound" as a verb as in ["to sound someone out"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sound+out) but that, obviously, is not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, ***"he brightens up a room"*** or ***"he lights up a room"***would most likely include sound since he is not a light source but rather a live, animated presence.

Comment: Or you could explicitly include sound: "Chad always livens up  a room with his happy sounds and racy tales."http://www.thefreedictionary.com/liven+up

Comment: That rather depends on the nature of the sound and it's effect on the people present.

Answer (score 1):

One particular form of adding sound is *[chatting up](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/chat)*

> To engage (someone) in light, casual talk: "He would be . . . chatting up folks from Kansas" (Vanity Fair).

You also might say *regale*

> entertain or amuse (someone) with talk:
>   *he regaled her with a colourful account of that afternoon’s meeting*

SUPPLEMENT

Or you could say *He **lilted** through the room*.  [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lilt) defines it as

> to sing or play in a lively cheerful manner

Comment: I would understand _chatting someone up_ to mean hitting on them. It [seems to be](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/chat+up) a British idiom but that is the only meaning I was aware of.

Comment: @terdon: "Chatting up" a person may connote hitting on them, but "chatting up a room" implies, well, making the rounds and talking to others. It can be found in [several contexts](http://www.google.com/#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=f107d0289567f1e7&q=%22chatting+up+the+room%22), including a bride talking to friends at the wedding reception, a restauranteer talking to customers in the dining room, etc. As a supplmental comment: though I like "chatting up the room," I'm not fond at all of "lilting through the room." It can be found on Google, too, but it describes _sounds_ & _music_, not _people_.

Comment: @J.R. I understand that, I am just pointing out that I, at least, was not aware of that meaning and would not have understood it in the intended way before reading this answer. I am likely not alone in this since this seems to be a "which side of the pond" difference.

Answer (score 1):

The intransitive verb form of *noise* means "to talk much or loudly."

By analogy with *lights up a room*, you could say that someone *noises up a room*.

Comment: Sorry, that just sounds awkward to me.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Well, it's an awkward concept to begin with...

Comment: That's ok, my answer was not as original! lol!

Answer (score 1):

"Sound" would bring in connotations of testing out the feeling of the room, as, say a comedian might, related to the nautical "sounding" meaning to test the depth of the water so you don't run aground.

One could "sound out" a room in this sense.

---

"Sound up a room" just sounds odd, and few people would have any idea what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

When you say “add noise,” I'm assuming you mean this in a negative light. In other words, instead of him telling compelling stories that hold people in rapt attention, the person in question is loud and boisterous, perhaps even uncouth. I'm interpreting your use of the word “noise” to mean *unwelcomed* noise.

With that in mind, I have these suggestions:

> *He **clamors for attention** wherever he goes*.

*Clamor* is defined by [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/clamor_8#clamor_15) as, *to shout or talk loudly*. It often refers to loud *demands* for something, but I think it could work for your overly loud friend if we say that he is *clamoring for attention*.

Other possibilities include:

> He **adds din** to the room wherever he goes.

(The word *din* can be [used as a verb as well as a noun](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/din?showCookiePolicy=true), so, technically, if you **really** wanted a verb for some reason, you could say, *He **dins** the room wherever he goes,* but I think the phrase “adds din” sounds more natural.)

You could also say:

> He **adds commotion** to the room wherever he goes.

It's not a verb; nevertheless, it might be the most accurate way to describe his boorish social skills.

Answer (score 1):

'Fill the room with sound' is how it would be used.
You can 'Quiet down' a sound, as in a teacher telling students to 'Quiet down'.

You could 'lift up' a sound, as in 'lift up your voice'.

You could 'sound a trumpet' (used as a verb) which would fill up the room with noise.
Then maybe you could 'sound a choir' in the same way, though I haven't heard it used that way.
You can 'sound an alarm', and this would be a verb.